# Dual booting Ubuntu with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have a Lenovo Yoga 2. The specs are the following:

- Intel i7 Processor (2.6 GHz)
- 225GB SSD, 25GB Hard drive
- Windows 10
- 8GB RAM

I want to dual boot a good version of Ubuntu. I had the following questions.

1. Given the specs, will dual booting slow down my computer in any way?
2. Any suggestions on the best Ubuntu image to use?
3. How much resources on my computer will this use up?

Comment: Just wait for 16.04 LTS at the end of next month. You can be running tests with 15.10 on USB right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I suggest you to test Ubuntu 14.04 **L**ong **T**erm **S**upport in a USB live stick.

If everything is fine go ahead and install it. If you have minor problem testing it, you can ask here for help or google the problem to solve it. I have installed it with plenty of software and games and it uses right now 10 GB of HD space.
Making dual boot the only resource it use is the HDD space. When you boot in windows, Ubuntu doesn't use RAM or anything. The little added time the PC takes is when you have to decide on which OS you want to boot.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you sure your mechanical drive is only 25GB? Or did you miss a zero?

1. The only negative effect of a dual boot is the space it will take up on the SSD. An extra OS, applications, etc, will take up space on your drive. There is no other performance downside to having a dual boot. When you are running one OS, the other will simply be a dormant part of your SSD. But it won't consume any RAM, CPU or anything like that. Performance wise, it will be exactly like having only one OS, except for the storage thing. Oh, and also maybe the few seconds it takes to choose between Ubuntu and Windows when cold booting the machine.
2. That is wholly a matter of taste. However, your hardware is quite decent, so I would advise *against* lightweight flavors such as Lubuntu. If you have a fair Internet connection, I would advise you to download a few different ones, and try them all from a Live USB (without installing). You can download Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu GNOME and Ubuntu MATE, and see which one you like the most. Although don't judge their performance from the USB run, as booting from a USB can often be slower than booting from your SSD. Anyhow, I recommend that you get the 16.04 version of all of them, since that is the current LTS. Make sure to get the 64-bit images rather than the 32-bit.
3. When you are running Windows, Ubuntu will not consume any processing power or RAM or anything like that. The same goes for vice versa. When you are running Ubuntu, the system itself requires very little. On a clean installation you should see your CPU at 0-3% and your RAM at maybe 8%, supposing you haven't opened any applications. After that, it's all a matter of what kind of software you run. Some will require a lot of resources, others will require very little.

I hope this answers your questions.